# Custom dropdown in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I want to build a dropdown in android app which looks like below when it is not clicked:

[image]

On clicking, it should look like this:

[image]

The user should be able to scroll the dropdown list by fling gesture (upward / downward) but the list should show only 3 elements at once.

I have no idea what this is called or how to achieve this. Any pointers will be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Try ListView http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: Can you please share some example where this has been achieved. It would help to get a bit more specific tips. Thanks!